# Left join using temporary table is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, row-number

I am trying to execute a "left join" on a table "x" but i need the "row_number", so i am using a temporary table with the "with" command but the query does not work and i receive the following error:

> SQL Error [156] [S1000]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

someone knows how fix this

```sql
SELECT telefoneEnriquecido1. FROM VPOTPRP P
    LEFT JOIN (
        WITH tel AS (
            SELECT
                ID_PROSP,
                DT_INC,
                ID_NUM_TEL AS novoTelefone,
                DT_ATC AS dataAtualizacao,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_PROSP ORDER BY DT_ATC DESC) AS rowNumber
            FROM
            VPOTTEL
        )
        SELECT
        FROM tel
        WHERE
        rowNumber = 1
    ) telefoneEnriquecido1 on p.ID_PROSP = telefoneEnriquecido1.ID_PROSP
```

Comment: Post the query you wrote as the error clearly shows you missed a semicolon or a closed bracket at the end of your query

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I'm sorry, I already edited from post

Comment: **The previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon**. Self-explaining, your CTE must be the first statement.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.  PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange syntax.  I always find CTEs embedded within a query to be confusing, although some databases support them.  I don't find that the CTE adds anything to the query; just use a subquery:

```
SELECT . . .   -- whatever columns you want
FROM VPOTPRP P LEFT JOIN (
     (SELECT ID_PROSP, DT_INC, ID_NUM_TEL AS novoTelefone,
             DT_ATC AS dataAtualizacao,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_PROSP ORDER BY DT_ATC DESC) AS rowNumber
      FROM VPOTTEL
     ) PL
     ON P.ID_PROSP = PL.ID_PROSP AND rowNumber = 1
```